# Optimizing arrayRotateLeft method

Tags: java, arrays, optimization

My method works but apparently for Hackerrank it's not fast enough when dealing with big numbers. How do I optimize it? n is the array size, k is the number of times the array's elements should be rotated left.

```
 public static int[] arrayLeftRotation(int[] a, int n, int k) {
        int[] holder = new int[n];
        for(int m=0; m<k; m++)
            {
      for(int b = 0; b<n; b++)
          {
          if(b==0) holder[n-1]=a[b];
          else holder[b-1]=a[b];
          }
          a = holder;
          holder = new int[n];
        }
        return a;
    }
```

Comment: Do you have to use an array?  You could use a `Deque` and remove elements from the head and add it to the tail.  If you require an array, then you should probably treat it as circular and have a pointer to the "first" element, and shift the pointer when rotating the array.

Comment: Well the parameters need to stay the same and I need to return an array.

Comment: If you require to use array, I don't think your code need to optimize

Comment: Maybe something along the lines of `System#arrayCopy` or `Arrays#copyOfRange` could optimize your method if any of those methods are intrinsic.  Otherwise I'd stick with StinePike's answer, as it's only O(n) instead of O(nk).

Comment: Yea StinePike's answer was the best. I started it off with a while loop lol which was like O(n^2). Didn't think there'd be a O(n) solution.

Comment: @Bloodluster Elliott's answer is most likely faster as `System#arrayCopy` utilizes native code to do what the OS does best, copying memory to other locations.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like following

```
public static int[] arrayLeftRotation(int[] a, int n, int k) {
    int[] b = new int[n]
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        b[i] = a[(i+k)%n]
    return b;
}
```

Comment: dam so much shorter

Comment: @Bloodluster.. it has to be faster for optimization not shorter . welcome to the SO. if you find any answer helpful you can upvote/accet it.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to implement this with [`System.arraycopy(Object src, int srcPos, Object dest, int destPos, int length)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-), and you can replace `n` with `src.length`. Something like,

```
public static int[] arrayLeftRotation(int[] src, int k) {
    int[] dest = new int[src.length];
    System.arraycopy(src, k, dest, 0, src.length - k);
    System.arraycopy(src, 0, dest, src.length - k, k);
    return dest;
}
```

You might also implement [@StinePike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/931982/stinepike)'s proposed solution in one line with an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) like

```
public static int[] arrayLeftRotation(int[] a, int k) {
    return IntStream.range(0, a.length).map(i -> a[(i + k) % a.length]).toArray();
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to benchmark this against StinePike's answer?  I'm curious to see if there's any difference.